# Export big data from PostgreSQL to AWS s3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have ~10TB of data in the PostgreSQL database. I need to export this data into AWS S3 bucket.

I know how to export into the local file, for example:

```
CONNECT DATABASE_NAME;
COPY (SELECT (ID, NAME, ADDRESS) FROM CUSTOMERS) TO ‘CUSTOMERS_DATA.CSV WITH DELIMITER '|' CSV;
```

but I don't have the local drive with 10TB size.

How to directly export to AWS S3 bucket?

Comment: Is your Postgres instance running inside or outside of AWS? If outside, then you have to worry about the connection being dropped and the total amount of time taken to transfer 10 TB.

Comment: Also, what are you going to do with the data once it's in S3? Does it make more sense to keep it as a single 10 TB file or break it into pieces?

Comment: Inside of AWS EC2

Comment: I just need it to migrate the data to RedShift

Comment: Is this a one-time move or repeated? If one-time, have you considered simply attaching a 10 TB EBS volume to the EC2 instance to hold the dump file?

Comment: Cool idea, thanks! This is one time move. I can also mount S3FS instead of EBS and this way I’ll get the file directly to S3 bucket

Comment: I was just asking that to get an understanding for what your options are. I definitely do _not_ recommend doing that.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but why?

Comment: Working on an answer now ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When exporting a large data dump your biggest concern should be mitigating failures. Even if you could saturate a GB network connection, moving 10 TB of data will take > 24 hours. You don't want to have to restart that due to a failure (such as a database connection timeout).

This implies that you should break the export into multiple pieces. You can do this by adding an ID range to the select statement inside the copy (I've just edited your example, so there may be errors):

`COPY (SELECT (ID, NAME, ADDRESS) FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ID BETWEEN 0 and 1000000) TO ‘CUSTOMERS_DATA_0.CSV WITH DELIMITER '|' CSV;`

You would, of course, generate these statements with a short program; don't forget to change the name of the output file for each one. I recommend picking an ID range that gives you a gigabyte or so per output file, resulting in 10,000 intermediate files.

Where you write these files is up to you. If S3FS is sufficiently reliable, I think it's a good idea.

By breaking the unload into multiple smaller pieces, you can also divide it among multiple EC2 instances. You'll probably saturate the database machine's bandwidth with only a few readers. Also be aware that AWS charges $0.01 per GB for cross-AZ data transfer -- with 10TB that's $100 -- so make sure these EC2 machines are in the same AZ as the database machine.

It also means that you can perform the unload while the database is not otherwise busy (ie, outside of normal working hours).

Lastly, it means that you can test your process, and you can fix any data errors without having to run the entire export (or process 10TB of data for each fix).

On the import side, [Redshift can load multiple files in parallel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html). This should improve your overall time, although I can't really say how much.

One caveat: *use a manifest file* rather than an object name prefix. I've run into cases where S3's eventual consistency caused files to be dropped during a load.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 9):

You can pipe the output of a program to s3, as such:

```
cat "hello world" | aws s3 cp - s3://some-bucket/hello.txt
```

I'm not massively experienced with `postgresql`, but from what I understand the following should work:

```
psql -U user -d DATABASE_NAME -c "Copy (Select ID, NAME, ADDRESS From CUSTOMERS) To STDOUT With CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';" | aws s3 cp - s3://some-bucket/CUSTOMERS_DATA.csv.gz
```

Comment: This approach worked for me just now, but there's nothing about it actually converting the files to gzip. So, anything that reads the `.gz` extension will be confused because the contents were just a plain csv.

Comment: If you want the contents to be gzip, you may be able to do that with another piped command inbetween the  `psql` and the `aws` ones. I'm not an expert, but it may be as simple as: `... | gzip | aws s3 cp ...`: https://askubuntu.com/a/744263/1064805