# AWS Data Pipelines - RDS Postgres to Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

Im trying to get an ETL happening using AWS Data Pipelines for RDS Postgres --> Redshift.

However the documentation https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/datapipeline-copy-tables/ dosent really help and looks to be old.

Has anyone got something recent that actually works with RDS Postgres --> Redshift. A simple script to grab everything from PSQL --> S3 --> Redshift (OVERWRITE) would be ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032312/export-big-data-from-postgresql-to-aws-s3

Comment: also, S3 is just a file storage. if you can export data from Postgres to files, and you can import data from files to Redshift, you are done :-)